# Why does Heroku only work when I also run the node app.js locally?

Tags: node.js, heroku, spotify

I have an app that I've built using Node.js and Spotify API. When I run the app locally on VS Code it works by going to localhost:8888. However after I deployed it on heroku I get an error when trying to click the Spotify login saying "The site cannot be reached", localhost refused to connect. The website link is vtraxx.herokuapp.com and I'll post some of the relevant code below:

EDIT: I changed my redirect to: https://vtraxx.herokuapp.com/callback and now nothing happens when you click "Log In to Spotify". I also forgot to edit the redirect in my config.js file but after doing that nothing still happens

EDIT2: I was able to get the login to somewhat work by changing the redirect to :vtraxx.herokuapp.com/login. However now I get an error that there are too many redirects. I cleared my cookies the first time and it was about to work but ultimately didn't.

app.js:

````
const request = require('request'); // "Request" library
const cors = require('cors');
const querystring = require('querystring');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const { config } = require('./config');

var client_id = 'client id'; // Your client id
var client_secret = 'client secret'; // Your secret
var redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8888/callback'; // Your redirect uri

/**
 * Generates a random string containing numbers and letters
 * @param  {number} length The length of the string
 * @return {string} The generated string
 */
var generateRandomString = function (length) {
    var text = '';
    var possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }
    return text;
};

var stateKey = 'spotify_auth_state';

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
    .use(cors())
    .use(cookieParser());

app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    var state = generateRandomString(16);
    res.cookie(stateKey, state);

    // your application requests authorization
    var scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email user-top-read';
    res.redirect(
        'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' +
            querystring.stringify({
                response_type: 'code',
                client_id: client_id,
                scope: scope,
                redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
                state: state
            })
    );
});

app.get('/callback', function (req, res) {
    // your application requests refresh and access tokens
    // after checking the state parameter

    var code = req.query.code || null;
    var state = req.query.state || null;
    var storedState = req.cookies ? req.cookies[stateKey] : null;

    if (state === null || state !== storedState) {
        res.redirect(
            '/#' +
                querystring.stringify({
                    error: 'state_mismatch'
                })
        );
    } else {
        res.clearCookie(stateKey);
        var authOptions = {
            url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
            form: {
                code: code,
                redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
                grant_type: 'authorization_code'
            },
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Basic ' + new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64')
            },
            json: true
        };

        request.post(authOptions, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                var access_token = body.access_token,
                    refresh_token = body.refresh_token;

                var options = {
                    url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
                    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token },
                    json: true
                };

                var topOptions = {
                    url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/tracks',
                    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token },
                    json: true
                };

                // use the access token to access the Spotify Web API
                request.get(topOptions, function (error, response, body) {
                    for (let i = 0; i < body.items.length; i++) {
                        console.log(body);
                    }
                });

                // we can also pass the token to the browser to make requests from there
                res.redirect(
                    '/#' +
                        querystring.stringify({
                            access_token: access_token,
                            refresh_token: refresh_token
                        })
                );
            } else {
                res.redirect(
                    '/#' +
                        querystring.stringify({
                            error: 'invalid_token'
                        })
                );
            }
        });
    }
});

app.get('/refresh_token', function (req, res) {
    // requesting access token from refresh token
    var refresh_token = req.query.refresh_token;
    var authOptions = {
        url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
        headers: { Authorization: 'Basic ' + new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64') },
        form: {
            grant_type: 'refresh_token',
            refresh_token: refresh_token
        },
        json: true
    };

    request.post(authOptions, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            var access_token = body.access_token;
            res.send({
                access_token: access_token
            });
        }
    });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8888, function () {
    console.log('Server is running on port 8888');
});```

I put the localhost:8888 in the spotify dashboard as well. This is my very first project and I'm not exactly sure I know what I'm doing but this is the final step to the finish product and I'm pulling my hair out. This is also my first time using node.js/JavaScript in general
````

Comment: Because your redirect URI is still to localhost.

Comment: Is Heroku supposed to give me a new URI? I apologize if my question is basic I'm new to all of this. What would I replace the localhost:8888 with?

Comment: Spotify will redirect your client back to where you told it to (within some limits, probably). At the moment you're telling it to redirect them to localhost - this works on your machine (when it's running locally), but won't work on anyone else's. So you need *configuration* to send them to your Heroku app's callback route in prod.

Comment: I was able to fix that issue but now when you click the login button I receive an error: too many redirects

Answer (score 0):

Your Heroku deployment is asking Spotify to redirect the browser back to `localhost`.  That's why it only runs when your app is running locally.

When your app is running locally, and Spotify redirects your browser to `localhost`, your browser is connecting to your local machine on port 8888.

When your app is running in Heroku, and Spotify redirects your browser to `localhost`, your browser is connecting to your local machine on port 8888.  It doesn't bring you back to Heroku.

Change `redirect_uri` so that it reflects the Heroku instance (the `herokuapp.com` URL) instead of `localhost`.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense, however (and please forgive me) if I change the redirect URL into https://vtraxx.herokuapp.com nothing will happen because it is just redirecting back into the front page. I appreciate the help though, I'm almost there!

Comment: Are you redirecting to the `/callback` route or just to the front page?

Comment: I'm redirecting to https://vtraxx.herokuapp.com/callback.
I'm assuming I also need to do the same on the Spotify Dashboard as well

Comment: All of the redirect calls within your `callback` function go to `/#` (along with some GET parameters).  That would send you back to your `/` route, which is your front page.

Comment: I was able to get that working but now I get an error that Spotify has too many redirects